# DIVs next to each other and prevent line breaks ( with css only)

Tags: css, html, css-float, width

I have 3 DIVs: 1. **suiteBar**, 2. **ribbonMain**, 3. **ribbonSub**

I like to display the DIVs in the following way:

DIV1 (suiteBar) : right (without a specific width)

DIV2 (ribbonMain) : left in the same line with DIV1 (width: 100%)

DIV3 (ribbonSub) : under DIV1+DIV2 over the full width from both DIVs

Is that possible? Everytime when I give my DIV2 a width from 100% it makes a 'line Break'... See my example on fiddle and code here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/dkHZS/

```
    #topHeader { 
    display: block;
}
#suiteBar {
    background-color: Aqua;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
#ribbon {
    background-color: Lime;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}
#ribbonSub {
    background-color: Gray;
}

<div id="topHeader">
  <div id="suiteBar">suiteBar</div>
  <div id="ribbon">ribbonMain
    <div id="ribbonSub">ribbonSub</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *inline* elements cannot be *floated* - Specify one or the other. Not both.

Comment: By giving 100% width to div2 how come you align another div in the same line?

Comment: @Simon - you're going to want to use overflow: hidden on the right `div`. See the fiddle I posted, I think that is what you're looking for. If not, just let me know and i'll remove it.

Comment: Hi Evan, I already tried it with the attribute 'overflow:hidden' but then some other functions from the DIV ribbonSub is not working anymore... So using the attribute 'overflow:hidden' is not possible for me...

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden` on the right div: http://jsfiddle.net/dkHZS/6/

You could do something like this:

```
<div id="left">

</div>

<div id="right">

</div>

<div id="bottom">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
   #left{
float:left;
width: 90%;
 background: green;
    height:20px;
}
#right{

    overflow:hidden;
    background: blue;
    height:20px;
}
#bottom{
width: 100%;
float:left;
    background: red;
    height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't float the ribbon div:

```
#suiteBar {
    background-color: Aqua;
    float: right;
}

#ribbon {
    background-color: Lime;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkHZS/4/

Also, when you float an element, it becomes a block element, so setting it to inline won't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. On fiddle this example is working. But when I try to use it in my site then the Ribbon DIV is overlaying the DIV suiteBar... Any ideas why? The rest is working.

Comment: Hard to guess, maybe there are other styles in play set on the elements having side-effects. Css-attributes like postition, float or z-index could be a source.

Comment: Ok its working for me if I replace 'position:relative' with 'position:static' in Chrome, Firfox and IE9+ it is working... but in IE8 not... Any ideas how I could fix this for IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle.

```
I use position.
```

This method also works good.

http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/NbX7P/